# Is there a way to feed a comma separated String to a feeder in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a comma separated String object like this:

```
(11,222,33)
```

Is there a way I can use this as a feeder in Gatling GET request?

Or do I need to convert this to a an Array to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You cannot directly use this.  You can convert to a map and feed or put this in a csv file and then use the file as reader.

Comment: Yeah. Can use Json as well. I was thinking if by someway I can use this directly.

Comment: Nope, IMO I don't think so.  You will have to do some modifications or write some randomiser code say split in your exec and randomly pick an index - so you are not using feeder but your own randomiser.

Comment: That's what I am doing right now. But was interested to check if there was some functionality like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar since feeder was  not what I wanted ...

- Create a simple Scala Object and put all your data with logic and import it  for eg

  `object GenerateInput 
    { 
      your code plus return Random.shuffle(jobsQue); 
    }`
- In your simulation class at the top

  `val yourScn= scenario("Requests").group("Groups"){
  asLongAs(session => jobsQue.length > 0) {
  exec { session => 
      var reportElement = jobsQue.pop()
      }`
- Now you have a unique data for each thread and every thread gets a unique record . My collection is a stack of objects

Comment: Cool. Let me try this.